# Update sql syntax - Reset a field to itself with a concatenation - SQLServer 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, syntax-error, sql-update, string-concatenation

I'm getting and error using this syntax:

```
update table set field1 = (field1+' - '+field2) where field1 = 'somevalue'
```

It's not too happy with doing this for me.  I know that the '+' for concatenation works in my select statements, so that is the right syntax.  There is something else at play here... and I tried removing the parenthesis too.

Example:

if field1 = 'Cheese' and field2 = 'ConQueso'
then my update should set all records where field1 = 'Cheese' to field1 = 'Cheese - ConQueso'

---

**EDIT:**

Both fields are text fields

Comment: What are the data types of field1 and field2? Also, what is the error you're getting? My guess is that you have incompatible data types and that's why it's failing out, but I'd like to find out from you if I'm right!

Comment: Re edit - then can you switch to varchar(max) instead? that'll fix it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to tell without you providing the error, but perhaps the combined data size exceeds field1.

E.g., if `field1` is varchar(50) and `field2` is varchar(50), the combined total could be up to 103 characters including your `' - '`, which exceeds the 50 characters of field1.

Comment: good thought, but this shouldn't be the case.... I'll copy the error into the question

Comment: you were right... thanks orbman... gotta modify the length of field1 and hopefully i can get away with that easily enough

Answer (score 2):

(edit: pre-dates the update clarifying data-type is `text`; but works fine as `varchar(max)`)

Works fine here (SQL2005):

```
create table [table] (
   field1 varchar(max) not null,
   field2 varchar(max) not null)
insert [table] values ('somevalue','abc')
insert [table] values ('other','def')
update [table] set field1 = (field1+' - '+field2) where field1 = 'somevalue'
select * from [table]
```

outputs:

```
field1               field2
-------------------- --------------------
somevalue - abc      abc
other                def
```

Comment: it should have worked for me too, but orbman made a good point.  I never checked the length of field1 and it just wouldn't all fit in there... thanks though